# How to specify number of paragraphs in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I Want to find number of occurrences of new line in perl using regex.
How to define number of occurrences of newline in perl.

For example
I have text containing

```
dog
cat
other 23 newlines
puppy
Kitten
```

I am able to do regex using notepad `Find "(dog)((?:.*[\r\n]+){25})(\w.*)"` and `replace with "\1 = \3 \2"`
**EDIT**

Important thing is that, How to find what is on paragraph 25 from dog.
More simpler way.
How to shorten this find string

```
(dog)(.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+)(.*)
```

what is the alternative to specific numbers of new lines in Perl?

By mistake posted on superuser, Now Moved here.

Comment: See for multi line match http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=17947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the lines when reading the input:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/dog/) {
        <> for 1 .. 24;
        print scalar <>;
    }
}
```

Or, if the whole string is the input, you can use a non-capturing group:

```
my ($puppy) = $string =~ /dog(?:.*\n){25}(.*)/;
print $puppy;
```

In a regex, a dot doesn't match a newline (unless the `/s` modifier is used).

Comment: So no one liner.. I am completely blank about perl. Just using for regex alternative of notepad++ Surely this will help. I think next step is to learn basics of per.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tr///` operator (see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)) to count the number of occurrences of a single character.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = 'dog
cat
other 23 newlines
puppy
Kitten';

print $string =~ tr/\n//, "\n";
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: This is great. Is there any single liner for regex find and replace. In my case I already know the number of paragraphs. How to do the replacement.

Comment: @Rahul: I don't understand. What do you want to replace with what?

Comment: Finding is more important for me as this is just exemplary case. I just want to know How to find that after finding dog, what is after 25 paragarph from dog. If I found that, printing dog=puppy is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer I wanted.

```
perl -i.bak -pe "BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(dog)(.*[\r\n]+){23}(.*)/$1 = $3/smg" 1.rtf
```